# What could be stopping DHCP from a computer connected to a specific switch?

Tags: networking, dhcp, switch, tcpip

I've recently replaced a number of 10/100 switches in our office with Gigabit managed switches and I've found that computers connected to one of the switches aren't getting DHCP leases from the server.
This isn't a huge issue because almost everything in the office uses static IP's, but I do have some areas of the office that have a wireless AP connected to this switch (through another managed switch first), and devices that connect to these AP's aren't getting DHCP leases.

I think I've determined that it is this switch because I have tested the following:

### server-switch-switch-client

Changing from `DHCP Server -- suspect switch in server room -- other managed switch 1 -- laptop with DHCP enabled` (no lease)

to `DHCP Server -- other switch in server room -- other managed switch 1 -- laptop with DHCP enabled` allows a DHCP lease straight away.

### server-switch-ap-client

Similarly, changing from `DHCP Server -- suspect switch in server room -- wireless AP -- laptop with DHCP enabled` (no lease)

to `DHCP Server -- other switch in server room -- wireless AP -- laptop with DHCP enabled` allows a DHCP lease straight away.

### server-switch-client

Lastly, changing from `DHCP Server -- suspect switch in server room -- laptop with DHCP enabled` (no lease)

to `DHCP Server -- other switch in server room -- laptop with DHCP enabled` allows a DHCP lease straight away.

The thing is, the suspect switch (call it Secondary Switch) is connected to the working switch (call this the Primary Switch).  The Primary Switch is connected to our Juniper router (the DHCP Server).  Other servers in the rack are all connected to the Primary Switch, as are the area switches around the office.  The only things currently directly connected to the secondary switch are the devices within ethernet cabling proximity to the server room, and these are all set with static addresses.
Nonetheless, I'd still like to get this suspect Secondary Switch configured correctly in case I have to load balance or use it as a failover switch to the Primary.

The suspect switch is a [D-Link DGS-1210-52 (link is to manual)](ftp://files.dlink.com.au/products/DGS-1210-52/Manuals/DGS-1210_Series_C1_User_Manual_v4.70(WW).pdf) running firmware version 3.10.013.

[image: Side-by-side overiew of the two main switches]

Comment: Seriously, you shouldn't have access ports on a distribution switch, and the access switches should not connect to each other. In any case, you want to make sure that the first switch to the router is the root bridge. Also, you need to detail any VLANs and configurations for those, and make sure that the switch-to-switch connections are set as trunks, not access ports.

Comment: yeah, my area of expertise isn't really in this level of networking.  I just copied settings from the original gigabit managed switch to the new gigabiet managed switch (the suspect one) and set different IP's,
So you're saying I should pick one switch to use as the distribution switch, and configure the ports that are used to connect the other switches (and AP's) as trunk ports?  And only have these other switches and AP's connected to this Distribution switch?
There's no trunking at all - http://imgur.com/a/02H30. And NO VLANs in use at all on any of the switches, ap's or endpoints.

Comment: Well, there is at least one VLAN: the default VLAN 1. You should have a distribution switch to which only access switches connect via trunks, even if you don't have multiple VLANs. There really should be no access ports on the distribution switch. It would be better if it is a layer-3 switch to do the LAN routing, and leave the WAN router alone for intra-site traffic, but you could use a layer-2 switch if the WAN router is doing the LAN routing. All your end-devices connect to the access switches. It's better if each access switch is on a different VLAN, which is not on the other switches.

Comment: One of the switches said link aggregation requires minimum 2 trunked ports, so I've just changed ports 47 and 48 on both switches to trunking.  The Secondary connects to Primary via port 48.  I've connected my laptop directly to one of the other ports on Secondary and did an IP release and renew.  I didn't get a DHCP lease and eventually got an APIPA address.
Connecting back to Primary and doing another release and renew and I got a DHCP lease straight away.  Any thoughts?

Comment: should i have both 47 and 48 on Secondary connected to 47 and 48 on Primary with straight-through patch cables?  Will this provide any benefit?

Comment: If you set up LAG you need to have the two switches connected on both ports. A LAG connection must have all the ports in the LAG group on one switch terminate on the ports of one other switch in a LAG group. You cannot split a LAG group to different switches. If the connections are copper, then either straight-through or crossover cables should work on modern switches. Fiber connections must be crossover.

Comment: Before setupping up a LAG, make your switch work please. Use a normal uplink and try again your DHCP. PortFast|STP can make a port wait before to get a connection, did you tried to re-issue a ipconfig /renew after some second ?

Comment: OMG, *distribution switches*. These are nasty plastic boxes, just *pretending* to be switches, they can connect in any possible way, nothing could make them actual switches.

Comment: or there is "dhcp snooping" configured

Answer (score 1):

the only thing that normally would stop a dhcp request reaching client and server is if there is no link between the switches/link not working , either tru VLAN issues or else

vlan issues: 
-uplink configured as access port whithin a diffrent vlan than dhcp AND routing not allowed or blocked from one vlan to another. 
-vlan does not exist in second switch
-trunk-uplink does not allow the vlan tru

trunk ==/== LAG ...

set a static ip on a laptop plug in 2nd switch and ping it from the dhcp-server if that works link works its your dhcp that is at fault. 
if it does not work your link is not working. (ip /ethernet wise)